# using api.ai my input is not recognised if missing an optional entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

my api.ai intent has three entities  $saluation, $given-name and $last-name.

$given-name is required.

user says - my name is mr jimmy smith (with 
mr marked as saluation, jimmy as given-name and smith as last-name)

text response - hi $saluation $given-name $last-name

if i input "my name is mrs elaine franks" i get the required response.
However if i input my name is elaine franks" i get "can you say it again" even though saluation is not required.

Anyone know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you added examples of phrases without the saluation? For example: "My name is Elaine Franks"

Comment: no i assumed that it would be smart enough to not need that. So every phrase has six possible combinations that need added? Sounds cumbersome

Comment: The more different options you put, the better will be the recognition. I think that if you put at least one option without the parameters it should work fine. Did it work?